# Why does only one of these .php functions work

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to put php results into an HTML table, and not sure why it is not working. The first block returns the data I need, so I know it's not a sql query issue. The second block (where I try to make it a table) returns the headers but no data.

#### Here is my code:

```
<h1>   
<?php
    while (odbc_fetch_row($weekadmissions)) // while there are rows
    {
       print odbc_result($weekadmissions, "date") . ", " .
             odbc_result($weekadmissions, "attendance") .
             "<br />\n";
    }
  ?>

</h1>


<?php
print "<table><tr>";
print "<th>Date</th>";
print "<th>Attendance</th></tr>";

  while (odbc_fetch_row($weekadmissions)) // while there are rows
  {
    print "<tr><td>" . odbc_result($weekadmissions,"date") . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . odbc_result($weekadmissions, "attendance") . "</td></tr>";
  }
print "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's probably because in the first `while` loop, the result is consumed (by consumed I mean at the end - no more results to read). Edit: you should either save the results to another variable so you can loop it any number of times or figure out a way to set to the beginning of results (which I don't know how to without research)

Comment: That's exactly what it was - thanks!

Comment: If you solved the problem, please, post how you did it and the results as an answer so the question doesn't stay unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that the result was consumed by the first loop - thank you FirstOne for the solution